# Why do few investors choose off book trading?

Tags: stocks, trading

What is off order book trading and how it is different from order book trading. 
When I check the 0r1O (LSE), Few websites show $1585.46 ( last order book trade which took place on 22nd of May) and few (e.g. yahoo ) return last price as $1802 which is an off book trade.

One more interesting fact I noticed is that Yahoo is returning last close as $1585.46 only which is the last order book trade ( took place on 22nd May ) though there have been continuous off book trades since then.

https://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/summary/company-summary/US0231351067USUSDSSX4.html

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/0R1O.L?p=0R1O.L

Edit: 
I wonder why few investors prefer off book trading over order book in such above cases. Since the last order book trade ( on 22nd of May ) this security has seen rise of $300 in it's price. Isn't it risky especially with this low amount of trading volume?

Comment: An Off-Book trade is one that takes place outside the order book - often the OTC market - and is then reported to the exchange.

Comment: Yes I read the definition but didn't get why investors would like to do that. Since 22nd May 0R1O.L has only seen off order book and still rises from $1.5k to $1.8K. Isn't it a risk because it has very low volume?

Comment: @user2611539 In that case, you should probably [edit] those details into question (that you understand the _term_, just not why people would use it), and probably change the title to something like "_Why would investors use off order book trading?_".

Comment: That makes sense. I have updated my question.

Comment: Why *should* you do off order book trades?

Comment: anyone can help here?